# Change class of rows in table 2 when a specific value of radio button in table 1 is checked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two tables, with radio buttons.  I have it set up to work nicely that when a radio button is checked, the corresponding row is highlighted.  This works independently in each table.  Now, if a certain value of radio button in table 1 is checked, I need it to un-highlight any previously checked rows in table 2.  It could be either ID "1E" or value "Fixed Income" from table 1 removes the highlight of table 2.

```js
$('input[name="radio1"]').click(function() {
    $(".checked").removeClass("checked");
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('.highOption').addClass('checked');
    }
});    

$('input[name="radio2"]').click(function() {
    $(".checked2").removeClass("checked2");
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('.highOption').addClass('checked2');
    }
});    

// I tried adding varieties of this, but I'm just not getting it right.
$('input[value="Fixed Income"]').click(function() {
    $(".checked").removeClass("checked");
    $(".checked2").removeClass("checked2");
});
```

```css
.checked {
    background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.5)
}
.checked2 {
    background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.5)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1A" name="radio1" value="Agressive">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Aggressive<br>(99)</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 1000%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>55%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1B" name="radio1" value="Agressive/Moderate">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Moderate/Aggressive<br>(97-98)</td>
        <td>80%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 80%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>45%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1C" name="radio1" value="Moderate">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Moderate<br>(93-96)</td>
        <td>60%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 60%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>35%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1D" name="radio1" value="Moderate/Conservative">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Moderate/Conservative<br>(85-92)</td>
        <td>40%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 40%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>28%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1E" name="radio1" value="Conservative">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Conservative<br>(51-84)</td>
        <td>20%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 20%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>20%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="1F" name="radio1" value="Fixed Income">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>Fixed Income<br>(1-50)</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#2453B7 0%, #44CF6C 0);"></div>
        </td>
        <td>10%</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<br><br>

<table>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="2A" name="radio2" value="Core 0%/Explore 100%">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#00108E 0%, #1089FF 0); align:center;"></div>
        </td>
        <td> 0%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highOption">
        <td>
            <label class="container">
                <input type="radio" id="2B" name="radio2" value="Core 25%/Explore 75%">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td> 75%</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="pie" style="background: conic-gradient(#00108E 25%, #1089FF 0); align:center;"></div>
        </td>
        <td> 25%</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$('input[name="radio1"]').click(function() {
        $(".checked").removeClass("checked");
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('.highOption').addClass('checked');
        }
    });


    $('input[name="radio2"]').click(function() {
        $(".checked2").removeClass("checked2");
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('.highOption').addClass('checked2');
        }
    });


    $('input[value="Fixed Income"]').click(function() {
        $(".checked").removeClass("checked");
        $(".checked2").removeClass("checked2");
    });
```

Comment: @AmirBill I isn't removing checked2  when value=Fixed Income is checked in radio1

Comment: @AmirBill nope, still no luck.  Where should it go in relation to the other functions?  Last seems to ignore it, first stops the whole thing from working.

Comment: add your `html` please

Comment: @AmirBill added, tried to take out all the unnecessary bits.

Comment: try my answer again :))

Comment: @AmirBill tyty!